# LTspice if statement

Tags: ltspice

I'm trying to change a voltage source value between 0V and 5V based on the value of another part. This part is also varying in value (a list of resistor values).

The voltage source "Select" should depend on the resistor "R" in its value.

I tried the parameters and functions in the picture below with the `if` statement, but none of them is working, and I am not sure what is wrong here.

[image: LTspice model]

Comment: Were you aware that in certain places, such as the voltage for a voltage source, that you need to wrap an expression with { and }? So, for example, you might write {Select} rather than Select? Just a question. I have not looked over your schematic with any care. So I'm not being pointed, yet. Just letting you think for a moment about it.

Comment: Tried it like that {Select}. Same error nothing changed.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using a behavioral voltage source (bv). This will allow you to use a formula for the voltage, such as this:

`V=5*({R}>5000)`

Here I've done this with two circuits (LTspice on this computer doesn't seem to display step commands correctly so I did it this way) the one where R is just below 5000\$\Omega\$ shows 0 V and where R is just above 5000\$\Omega\$ shows 5 V. You should also be able to use `V=5*({R}>=5000)` if you want to include 5000 in the range.

[image: behavioral voltage source]

Going back and looking at the if statement idea I tried this out and it appears to work. I can't say I'm crazy about using the same name for a parameter and a node, such as with *select*, I would name one of them something else. It seems to work as is but the programmer in me wants to avoid name clashes. If there's a difference between this and what you've tried I'm not seeing it, perhaps your LTspice has gotten mucked up on this one and you just need to start over with a fresh new schematic.

[image: if statement voltage source]

Comment: This might be a good way to deal with that issue. Thank you ,will use it as an option.

Comment: @Elektroneu Have a look at my update. I was able to get the if statement to work. The behavioral source is a good way to go too, I use them as signal sources for audio simulations, I can set up all the params and have the formula take care of things like pk-pk to RMS calculation.

Comment: I duplicated @Elektroneu 's circuit (see link), and it works for me.  I believe the extra spaces in the `.param` equation are what's causing the issue.  They error out for me, but maybe they're reduced to warnings in newer versions??? (I use an older version).  Also, +1000 for pointing out the bad practice of having a parameter, node name, and reference designator all be the same name.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTcqk.png

Comment: Thanks a lot GodJihyo! This is totally working. I think there was a space somewhere that caused the problem as Ste Kulov suggested.